# XCode Source Control File Owner

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4

I am using XCode 4.5 and I use the build in Source control, I have modify a file and still not committed, I tried to access this file form another iMac and modify the same file and there is no problem with modifications.

The issue is how I can own this file and no other developer can modify it until I commit it?

Answer (score 0):

Using git? You don't. That's not how git works, there's no concept of "file locks" and they wouldn't make sense in a distributed version control system. You'll have to actually talk to the other developers if you think it is important to avoid merge conflicts on that file.

Comment: so how I can avoid conflict between developers?

Comment: That depends on why you think conflicts are a problem in the first place and what sort of file you want to lock access to. If this is a binary or other file type which you really cannot merge then the best solution is probably to have the team communicate what they are doing regularly and make small focused changes. Otherwise just let them merge the changes.

Comment: In fact I am using MS Source Save when I develop .Net applications and the source save not allow more than one developer to modify a file at a time, and this way I'll be sure no other developer change or delete some code I already use it in my task